# I need to rewrite an onclick function to the code which can be handled for Google AMP

Tags: amp-html, dom-events

I wrote like `on="tap:supplier_whatsapp_146_2933[.track_number_whatsapp(client_id=146,car_id=2933)]"`

But it is giving me error like  **invalid action definition**. Please somebody help me to solve this error?

> Invalid action definition in a#supplier_whatsapp_146_2933:
>      [tap:supplier_whatsapp_146_2933[.track_number_whatsapp(client_id=146,car_id=2933)]];
>       expected [:]

Comment: Where did you get this? Have you checked the [amp documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/) of this is valid? Also, you have written `on="tap:supplier_whatsapp_146_2933[.track_number_whatsapp(client_id=146,car_id=2933)]"`. Have you checked `supplier_whatsapp_146_2933[.track_number_whatsapp(client_id=146,car_id=2933)]` if it's a valid action? Have you checked [this github post](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-actions-and-events.md)?

Comment: In the existing code , it is wriiten as onclick function . I am revamping the website using amp .function track_number_whatsapp() is defined in the page.How can we rewrite the custom javascript like this in a good way in amp?Any idea?